# Range "Object Required"

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure this out.

```
Sub Paste1()
    Dim NextRow As Range
    Set NextRow = Range("A" & Sheets("AMCurrent").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1)
    AMPaste.Range("A3:F3").Copy
    AMCurrent.Activate
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

I get an "object error" on row 4, `AMPaste.Range("A3:F3").Copy`.

Comment: what is `AMPaste` is it the name of the sheet, the code name of the sheet, or a public worksheet variable?

Comment: You didn't declare the AMPaste as a worksheet, same with AMCurrent..

Comment: I am working off of someone else's code and new to it.  They had "Sheet1" in place of "AMCurrent" and "Sheet2" in place of "AMPaste".  They are the names of the worksheets.

Comment: When they were using `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` they were using the code name of the sheets and not the actual name of the sheets.  I will bet the code name is still something like `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`

Comment: Google `Worksheet Code name VBA` and you will find many articles on the difference, and how to use in code.

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks a ton!  I thought that it changed it completely.  Lots to learn.

Comment: See [cant access a different sheet getting #VALUE! error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48727089/cant-access-a-different-sheet-getting-value-error/48727117#48727117).

Comment: Using Range without preceding it with a worksheet reference, as in `AMCurrent.Range("A" & ...` may be why it's not finding the object originally.  Especially if your Activated worksheet changes

Comment: Excellent resources and information.  Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you didn't declare your Worksheets, and that you used their name instead of Sheets("SheetName"), but I believe this could be your solution:

```
 Sub Paste1()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    Dim wsPaste As Worksheet: Set wsPaste = Sheets("AMPaste")
    Dim wsCurrent As Worksheet: Set wsCurrent = Sheets("AMCurrent")

    NextRow = wsCurrent.Cells(wsCurrent.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    wsPaste.Range("A3:F3").Copy
    wsCurrent.Range("A" & NextRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you so much!  This worked perfectly.  Excited to pick it apart and learn it.

Comment: @Heather, please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Comment: I've got to wait a few minutes but definitely will do.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My worksheet was named "tagsListSheet" and in my script I had a Worksheet variable also named "tagsListSheet". My line of code that produced your error looked like:

```
Set wwTags = Range(tagsListSheet.Cells(2, 2), tagsListSheet.Cells(lastTagRow, 2))
```

and when I changed the name of the worksheet variable, it worked.

```
Set wwTags = Range(tagSheet.Cells(2, 2), tagSheet.Cells(lastTagRow, 2))
```